# Why won't my GenericForeignKey cascade when deleting?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, cascading-deletes, django-contenttypes, generic-foreign-key

I'm creating a custom commenting system which can attache comments to any model using the contenttypes GenericForeignKey.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField(verbose_name='Comment')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

It is my understanding that when the model the comment is attached to is deleted, the delete should cascade and remove the comment as well.

Unfortunately, this isn't happening and I'm stumped.  Are there any common reasons why the default delete behaviour would change?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No, the documentation doesn't say that. What it says is that if you define a `GenericRelation` on a model - ie the reverse side of the `GenericForeignKey` - then when the item with the generic FK is deleted, the item with the GenericRelation will also be deleted.

> Unlike ForeignKey, GenericForeignKey does not accept an on_delete
>   argument to customize this behavior; if desired, you can avoid the
>   cascade-deletion simply by not using GenericRelation, and alternate
>   behavior can be provided via the pre_delete signal.

Comment: Thanks, I misread that piece of the documentation and assumed it meant it would cascade by default.

Comment: I think django docs should state this the other way round. "GenericForeignKey does NOT cascade delete instead it sets the value to null. It cascades ONLY if GenericRelation is used in the related model.". This is needed because we get cascade delete by default in normal foreign keys.

Answer (score 15):

I realise this is a **very** old question so it's possible things are different from when this was asked, but the accepted answer had me chasing down a rabbit hole this morning, therefore I wanted to leave this here to prevent future generations sharing my pain.

From the docs:

> Note also, that if you delete an object that has a GenericRelation, **any objects which have a GenericForeignKey pointing at it will be deleted as well**. In the example above, this means that if a Bookmark object were deleted, any TaggedItem objects pointing at it would be deleted at the same time.

This is the opposite of what the accepted answer is saying. Imagine the following:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField(verbose_name='Comment')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class Post(models.Model):
    comment = GenericRelation(Comment)
```

In the above example, if your Comment object has a Generic Foreign Key pointing to a Post object, then when the Post object is deleted any Comment objects pointing to it will also be deleted.

This is the expected behaviour and operates the same as a normal ForeignKey. Using the same example above, if the User object that the Comment object points to is deleted, the Comment will also be deleted.

If you happen to chance across this question because you need the reverse of this behaviour, i.e. when you delete the Comment the Post is also deleted, then you will likely need to employ the power of [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/).

Comment: I don't think this is true, at least in 2022. From django docs: "If the related object is deleted, the content_type and object_id fields remain set to their original values and the GenericForeignKey returns None"

Answer (score 3):

In addition to previous answers - if you have more complex structure and something like `GenericOneToOne` (which is not present in straight way in Django):

```py
class Post(models.Model)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    body = models.TextField(verbose_name='Comment')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    class Meta:
        # Constrain equals to OneToOne relation.
        unique_together = ('content_type', 'object_id')

class Author(models.Model):
    comment = GenericRelation(Comment)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And you want to delete `Post` and be sure that `Comment` and `Author` are deleted as well you need to write custom `post_delete` signal:

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_delete, sender=Comment, dispatch_uid='delete_comment_content_object')
def delete_comment_content_object(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    instance.content_object.delete()
```

If you override `delete` method of `Comment` class like this:

```py
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.content_object.delete()
    super().delete(args, kwargs)
```

It will delete `Author` **only** if you delete `Comment`. If you delete `Post` `Author` object will stay in database.